# Unable to use openldap olcTLS attributes

Tags: openldap, starttls, centos8

I've been working on trying to migrate an openldap instance from CentOS7 to CentOS8. RHEL deprecated the openldap packages in RHEL8, so I've been trying to migrate to the Symas packages.

- https://symas.com/openldap-for-linux-now-available-for-rhel-8/
- https://repo.symas.com/sofl/rhel8/

With the Symas packages installed, I've actually been able to get everything migrated over and working with the exception of TLS for STARTTLS. It seems that it doesn't recognize any of the olcTLS* attributes. I'm assuming that's schema related somehow but if someone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

tls.ldif:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/ca.crt
```

Results:

```
# ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f tls.ldif
modifying entry "cn=config" 
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
#
```

SELinux is currently disabled, the LDAP user/group recursive own everything under '/etc/openldap'. Googling has yielded many many results, but none of them covering procedures for TLS/STARTTLS on CentOS8 that I have found.

Comment: I note that it initially said 'invalid attribute *type*.' Makes me wonder whether you have the required schema loaded. Turn up the debugging level and have a look in the server log. Now possibly something wrong with the certificate or its location.

Answer (score 2):

After a ton of digging, I determined the issue to be a problem with my private key, and so it refused to set the TLS options altogether. But I'll be inclusive of everything I had to verify here for this error.

So for starters, you need to make sure the public/private keys are producing the same hash (This was where my issue was) -

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in /path/to/public.crt | openssl md5
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in /path/to/private.key | openssl md5
```

Then, from the [Debian guide](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/OpenLDAPSetup) -

> If the modifications fail with ldap_modify: Other (e.g.,
>   implementation specific) error (80), check the file paths for typos,
>   and ensure the files are readable by the openldap user.

Use sudo to run commands as the ldap user to validate this. For example:

```
sudo -u ldap cat /path/to/public.crt
```

Or

```
sudo -u ldap file /path/to/public.crt
```

You may have to additionally look into SELinux if the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Ubuntu 20.04 and I've been searching for answer for hours... The solution was to **turn off slapd before adding or modifying olcTLS options**. It is so stupid, because CentOS doesn't really care.

`systemctl stop slapd`

Then add the record:

`ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f your_file.ldif`

Though I've read that the order you add olcTLS records matter or that olcTLSCA settings should not be added if you use self-signed certs - all this seems to be false. This is my olcTLS file:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ldap/sasl2/server.crt
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ldap/sasl2/server.key
-
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ldap/sasl2/ca.crt
-
add: olcTLSCACertificatePath
olcTLSCACertificatePath: /etc/openldap/sasl2
```

Also don't forget to set the owner:group to openldap

`chown -R openldap:openldap /etc/openldap/sasl2`

And permissions:

`chmod 0600 /etc/openldap/sasl2/*`

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything I could find in every possible thread on this, all to no avail. What finally worked was to first delete the existing olcTLSCertificateKeyFile entry:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
```

Then add it via a separate ldif file:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: xxx
```

(Yes, the key absolutely 100% belongs with the existing olcTLSCertificateFile cert, triply-checked via openssl modulus, etc.)